# How to use Array.push and return the pushed item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calling `return someArr[someArr.push(newItem)-1];` and it does pretty what it should.

Wondering is there a syntactic "sugar" for that **extremely common** operation? I wonder because returned new `length` is indeed more rarely needed, than actual constructed object (which caller definetely may want to polulate). Or is that made because it actually will return "a copy of an object", and my edits to its fields "will not survive" in actual tree?

Just like a JS <= 1.2 did: `return someArr.push(newItem);`

Just want to know - Is there are new "replacement" method, that I am unaware of?

---

Also I had a minor subquestion *"does that return an 'independent' copy of an object or a 'reference' to actual object?"* but simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/4eyvbg29/) by [@PatricRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) just figured out that it is actually a reference (as it was expected), so I've credited him, for his assistance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also do it using a [logical and (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
return someArr.push(newItem) && newItem;
```

Since the array length will be positive after the push, the right-most expression will be evaluated and its value returned.

> This syntax is less clear than @adiga's answer using the comma operator though.

However, I personally prefer to return the new item on a new line to make it **more readable**:

```
someArr.push(newItem);
return newItem;
```

Comment: First syntax using `&&` much less readable than using the comma operator. The implication using `&&` is that if `push()` returns a falsy value then `newItem` is not returned. Any sane developer would have a double take at that before realizing `push()` always returns a truthy value, then _shame_ the developer who implemented this nasty shortcut before changing it to the second block with two much simpler statements.

Comment: I agree that it makes it less readable and isn’t even really *cooler*.  I think your last approach is for sure the better way to go.

Comment: I totally agree with you, this is why I mentionned I would return the item on another line. I will mention @adiga's answer as I find it clearer too. But I will personally never return the item on the same line though.

Comment: I think that `&&` is for lazy eval, when you need to evaluate second only if first it not `null`, `undefined`, `zero`, `false` or somehow otherwise "empty", like an empty string. DIfferences here: `f=()=>{return ""&&1;}` will output `""`, and `f=()=>{return "",1;}` will output 1, which is unwanted if `push()` failed. I will stick to your stuff, because if `push()` fails I must ignore newly created object and detect this (returned zero instead of an valid object). With comma operator I will just not detect insertion failure in code.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Like this:

```
return (someArr.push(newItem), newItem)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
someArr.push(newItem);
return newItem
```

Comment: I came from C/C++. Is a `newItem` a pointer/reference? Or is it an object(value) itself (that will be just copied)? Javascript is so hard to get it, much harder than plain assembler/basic/c/pascal, or even abstracted C++...

Comment: If it's an object, it will keep the reference. Basically, there is no difference between your code and this.

Comment: lets assume `a=x[i]`, let `a` be `i`-th element of array `x`. I am asking: is `return a` = "create new object `a`, copy fields from `x[i]`. any subsequent modifications of `a` the fields will not affect to` x[i]`. Or is it return Pointer/Reference = "return a pointer to actual memory location of x[i]. any edits of a field `a` will edit actual parent object fields `x[i]`?" Its unobvious in JS!

Comment: Difference will be here: `someArr.push(newItem); return newItem;`.. then after we got return: `newItem.field=123; alert(someArr[someArr.length-1].field);` a copy(C/C++) will yield `null` or `undefined`(there is no field in parent, because just object copy was modified - indeed what was returned in C++ was an object copy). A reference or a pointer will yield to 123. You got my question now?

Comment: @xakepp35 Depends on what `x[i]` is. If it's a primitive like boolean or number, then updating `a` won't affect the `x[i]` element. If it's an object, it will update the `x[i]` item

Comment: `var a = [{ b: 10}]; var c=a[0]; c.b = 20; alert(a[0].b);` ... **what is it?** 10(C++ object) or 20(C++ reference)?

Comment: @xakepp35 Sorry, deleted previous comment. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cve9zqjk/

Comment: @adiga it doesn't matter whether `a` is a primitive or non-primitive, any assignment that starts with `a = ...` won't affect what `x[i]` is. Any assignment that attempts to modify a member of `a` _will_ affect `x[i]`.

Comment: `var a = [{ b: 10}]; var c=a[0]; c.b = 20; alert(a[0].b);` ... **what is it?** 10(C++ object) or 20(C++ reference)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts of course, reassigning won't change the original array. I was talking more of updating an property of the variable if it;s an obejct. Check the fiddle I created.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts So it is an object.. bad. How do i return a reference? I need output 20! PS. its not array, its TREE! (index cant work!)

Comment: @xakepp35 stop comparing languages. It's a reference. This is what I was talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/4eyvbg29/

Comment: @xakepp35 basically, you *reassign* the variable, it will point to the new reasigned object's location. It won't affect the original array's object it was pointing to to. This is same as C#. You modify a property in the variable, it will still point to that object in the array and it will change array item. (Patrick's fiddle demonstrates this)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Got that, that's exactly what i was needed to ensure! So I am free in "recursively searching and returning objects from tree" and editing it and be sure that actual tree objects are edited

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've credited your effort in a question body, if you allow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by returning an assignment to the index of the current `.length`.

```
return someArr[someArr.length] = newItem;
```

The result of the assignment is the item being assigned, so that's what will be returned.

Assigning to the current `.length` of the array automatically expands it. Note that assigning to any index higher than the current `.length` will leave holes in the array.

Comment: Another great candidate, could be a viable stuff!.. How to select a winner? Should we benchmark the results and compare outcome? Which version of V8 should'v select?))))))

Comment: @xakepp35 premature optimization is the root of all evil. Don't even bother benchmarking. _If_ at some point you have a performance issue, I'm sure there are many more things that can more significantly impact the performance before this even makes a blip on the performance snapshot.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: While it's certainly a micro optimization that's likely not worth the trouble, it doesn't fall into the realm of premature optimization that Knuth described. For that to be the case, it would need to add too much complexity/confusion to the code for too little optimization. Here, the optimization (if any) is tiny, but so is the added complexity (if any).

Comment: The fact alone that this answer requires an explanation to validate that it causes the same side-effect (due to how the array exotic object modifies its `length` property when a value is assigned to a slot with an index greater than or equal to its `length`), I'm pretty sure it would fall into the realm, if it's even an optimization at all.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I'd tend to disagree. All syntax features require explanation to beginners;  Knuth was addressing experienced software engineers. What Knuth was concerned with was major structural changes that would be difficult to comprehend and maintain long term while only providing minimal benefit. That said, I avoid using the result of assignment, except in the rare case. If OP wants this behavior, they should create a utility function or subclass Array with a method (if legacy requirements allow them).